# JWTAuth authentication with username instead of email

Tags: php, api, laravel, authentication

Is there any way to use in laravel [jwt-auth](http://ift.tt/1GFm4Yr) the authentication using **username** (or any custom column), instead of an **email**?

This is the existing code

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    try {
        // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

I want to do Something like this

```
$credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');
```

One way is to put **usernames** in **email** column but that is a bad solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a way [here](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens)

We can grab a user from model (on the base of custom fields) like

// grab some user

```
$user = User::first();
```

and authenticate it manually.

```
$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Looking around](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/540), it looks like it is possible to do this by setting the credentials like so `$credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');`.

So all up it would look like this:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        // grab credentials from the request
        //$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        // Change email to username
        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

        try {
            // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        // all good so return the token
        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
```

Comment: Is this useful for use in Laravel 8?

Comment: @FernandoTorres sorry, I don't understand your question? `$request->only()` still works in Laravel 8...

Comment: I was asking you that if this solution works in Laravel Version 8.x using the most recent version of jwt

Comment: @FernandoTorres I don't know. I don't actively use this package. You could give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use case for login with email or username    
public function login(Request $request){
            // Request input contains username, email and password
            if ($request->has(['username', 'email', 'password'])) {
                $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
            } // Request input contains `enter code here`username and password
            elseif ($request->has(['username', 'password'])) {
                $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');
            } // Request input contains email and password
            elseif ($request->has(['email', 'password'])) {
                $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
            }
            else {
                $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
            }

            try {
               if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['invalid_email_or_password']);
               }
            } catch (JWTAuthException $e) {
                return response()->json(['failed_to_create_token'], 500);
            }
            return response()->json(compact('token'));
        }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code, since a code-only post does not really answer the question (and is not very helpful for other readers of this question).